# keep footer last in list when dragging new item into the list from another

Tags: vuedraggable

I have Vue Draggable working like a Kanban board with multiple columns, and I have made each column at least the height of the viewport so that each item can easily be dragged into the column next to it (for cases where one column is much longer than the next, for example).

I also have a button in the footer slot to add new cards to the column. This works well in that it is generally always at the bottom of the list, is not draggable, etc.

The issue arises when I drag an item from another list in *below* the footer (but still within the height of the draggable element). When I do this, the footer does not stay below the new item, which looks odd.

Once I drop the element, it snaps into place and the footer is one again at the bottom - it is only when the new card is being moved that it appears below the footer.

Is there any way to make sure that even during the move event and a new card being added to a list that the footer stays as the last element?

This issue seems to be captured in this comment on Github issues - https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/673#issuecomment-554149705 - but no solution is provided in that thread.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone having the same issue I solved this by doing the following:

1. Hooking into the `onMove` event using the `:move` prop to run a function each time an item is moved... e.g. `:move="fixFooter"`
2. Creating a function that checks if the moved item would be the last in the new list (thus by default it would sit below the footer without this fix), and if so on the `$nextTick` append the footer to the Draggable container so it gets moved below the item coming in to the list... (just learnt that `.appendChild` will move an existing element to the end)
3. It then checks if the from/to list is the same to account for the item being dragged *back* into the list it's coming from during the same drag event (otherwise you get the same undesirable footer behaviour as before if you drag an item out of a list and back below the footer without dropping it).

```
fixFooter(e) {
  if(e.relatedContext.list.length === e.draggedContext.futureIndex) {
    var newListDom = e.relatedContext.component.$el;
    var newListFooter = e.relatedContext.component.$slots.footer[0].elm;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      newListDom.appendChild(newListFooter);
    });
  } else if(e.from === e.to && (e.from.children.length - 1) === e.draggedContext.futureIndex) {
    var currentListDom = e.from;
    var currentListFooter = e.from.lastChild;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      currentListDom.appendChild(currentListFooter);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like for vue draggable next this is enough:

```
fixFooter(e) {
  if (e.relatedContext.list.length === e.draggedContext.futureIndex) {
    var newListDom = e.to

    var newListFooter = e.to.lastChild
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      newListDom.appendChild(newListFooter);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else if having an issue with this using **vue draggable next**, this works for me:

```
function fixFooter(e) {
  if (e.relatedContext.list.length === e.draggedContext.futureIndex) {
    let newListDom = e.to

    let newListFooter = e.to.lastChild
    nextTick(() => {
      newListDom.appendChild(newListFooter);
    });
  }else {
    let currentListDom = e.from;
    let currentListFooter = e.from.lastChild;
    nextTick(() => {
      currentListDom.appendChild(currentListFooter);
    });
  }
}
```

Then add `:move="fixFooter"` to your draggable element.